How to encrypt JWT Token-Oracle Java code
We have created JWT Token following the Oracle link: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fusionapps/HCM/JWT_API_Authentication_OBE/html/index.html
And we will use this token to execute Oracle HCM REST APIs.
Now the need is, we have to encrypt this token. Oracle is suggesting, we can encrypt the token using JSON Web Encryption (JWE) but not shared the steps or code?
need help on the steps or code or any Oracle link, which have details on code part.
Followed the link:https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fusionapps/HCM/JWT_API_Authentication_OBE/html/index.html
